# SQL Server conditional query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table for attendance entries looking like this :

[image]

I need a query to export the following format :

[image]

which present the Check-in and Check-out timings using British/French format (103)

I tried the following query :

```
SELECT 
    UserID, 
    (SELECT MIN(checktime) 
     FROM [FingerPrint].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT] I 
     WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), i.checktime, 111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), p.checktime, 111)  
       AND i.userid = p.userid),   
   (SELECT MAX(checktime) 
    FROM [FingerPrint].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT] I 
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), i.checktime, 111) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), p.checktime, 111) 
      AND i.userid = p.userid)
FROM 
    [FingerPrint].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT] p
GROUP BY 
    p.checktime, p.UserID
```

Basically I need a query to select the minimum time (check-in) and maximum time (check-out) for each day using the export format above, yet when there is no value for check-in and check-out, then query should return (null) for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you start with something like this:

```
SELECT  UserId, 
        CAST(CheckTime As Date) As CheckDate, 
        MIN(CheckTime) As CheckIn, 
        MAX(CheckTime) As CheckOut
FROM [FingerPrint].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
GROUP BY UserId, CAST(CheckTime As Date)
```

For older versions of sql server (2005, 2000), you can use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to `char(10)` to isolate the `date` part of the `datetime` column:

```
SELECT  UserId, 
        CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102) As CheckDate, /*Convert datetime format to Date*/
        MIN(CheckTime) As CheckIn, 
        MAX(CheckTime) As CheckOut
FROM [FingerPrint].[dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
GROUP BY UserId, CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102)
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a854/4)

Then you need to figure out what you want to display if the user have only one record for a day.

Also, what happens on night shifts, when a user checks in on one date, and checks out on the other date?

A better solution would be to add a bit column to specify if the record is for check in or for check out.

### Update

Using [`case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(v=sql.90).aspx) you can check if the current time is before or after whatever time of day you want to set up as the delimiter between check in and check out. In this example I've used 12 pm.

```
SELECT  UserId, 
        CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102) As CheckDate, /*Convert datetime format to Date*/
        CASE WHEN MIN(CheckTime) <> MAX(CheckTime) THEN
          MIN(CheckTime) 
        ELSE
          CASE WHEN MIN(CheckTime) < DATEADD(Hour, 12, CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102), 102)) THEN 
            NULL
          ELSE
            MIN(CheckTime)
          END
        END As CheckIn, 
        CASE WHEN MIN(CheckTime) <> MAX(CheckTime) THEN
          MAX(CheckTime) 
        ELSE
          CASE WHEN MAX(CheckTime) > DATEADD(Hour, 12, CONVERT(Datetime, CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102), 102)) THEN 
            NULL
          ELSE
            MAX(CheckTime)
          END
        END As CheckOut
FROM [CHECKINOUT]
GROUP BY UserId, CONVERT(char(10), CheckTime, 102)
```

[Here is the relevant fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a854/9)

Comment: sorry, i am using SQL Server 2005, what should i use instead of
    'Date' 
for Cast function? now i am getting 'Type Date is not a defined system type.'

Comment: You should have tagged your question with the version tag (I've already done that for you). Anyway, see my edited answer.

Comment: my bad, and thanks for the tag, my problem is that users are not committed to selecting the proper function (In and Out) and we have only one shift, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: As for one entry case, it should give a blank record as you can see in the result file, also format should match, what should i do?

Comment: This code is showing "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'FingerPrint.dbo.CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87685/discussion-between-ahmed-ali-and-zohar-peled).